# Eclipse Open Declaration Error - Does not resolve to a Javascript element

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, nodeclipse

I am running the Node.js plugin in Eclipse (Nodeclipse). Whenever I try to do open declaration (f3) on a function inside a js file, Eclipse gives me the error

> "Current text selection does not resolve to a Javascript element"

Inside my .project file, the project nature is as follows:

```
<natures>
        <nature>org.nodeclipse.ui.NodeNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
        <nature>tern.eclipse.ide.core.ternnature</nature>
</natures>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check/share your project natures in .project files

Comment: @PaulVerest please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, the message comes from JSDT, and to get rid of it, one would need to remove JDST nature, that is remove `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>` line.

Comment: so , why it doses not find the existing functions?